# jQuery content loading script - Help finding the code

Tags: jquery, dynamic, loading

Afternoon all,

Im trying to find a jquery content loading script,

im currently developing a video site,

(for example if the user clicks most viewed it will change the videos getting the source of the videos from a php document)

```
<div id="video-section" class="with-ads">
<!-- Videos Go Here -->
</div>
```

can someone point me of a decent script that will work?

Thank you.

Comment: A simple solution, is using jquery .load() or .get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would just want to do a .load similar to this

```
<a href="#" id="mostviewed">Most Viewed</a>
<div id="video-section" class="with-ads">
<!-- Videos Go Here -->
</div>​

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mostviewed').click(function(event) {
        $('#video-section').load('WHEREEVER YOUR PHP FILE IS HERE');
    });
});​
```

with load you can even shoot an action or something similar if you want to group your video data into one file i.e. most viewed, featured, whatever.